# Reload a section of page using javascript

Tags: visualforce

How to reload a specific section of a page on change of picklist value using javascript in visualforce page.

Comment: You can use ActionFunction or ActionSupport **reRender** attribute to make this happen. You just need to pass the Id of the element or section which you need to refresh/reload. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096q4IAA

Comment: I want to do it without controller method. Only using javascript function.

Comment: Then you have to do all rerender logic in JS.